# How to search and highlight certain word with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, highlight

Is there any way to use something like `ctrl+f` for searching words on web page? How to search and highlight certain word on web page using Java and Selenium?
For example, I need to search for word "test" on this web page: https://www.wedoqa.com/blog/
I tried to make some mix of the answers, so I write a code like this:

```
WebElement matchedElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='test']"));
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');", matchedElement);
            if(driver.getPageSource().contains(matchedElement.toString())) {
                System.out.println("The page contains word: " + matchedElement.toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println("The page does not contains word asdfghjkl");
            }
```

But, then I got error like this:

```
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[text()='test']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:317)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:419)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:309)
    at test.Test1.main(Test1.java:59)
```

Comment: Kindly let us know what have you tried so far ?

Comment: your code trials and error trace.

Comment: @Prany I dont' even have any idea how to do that... I don't any code... I know how to find some element and I saw many tutorials how to higlight element, but no single one how to find and higlight certain word.

Comment: @cruisepandey As I told to Prany, I don't have any code yet. I'm asking for simplyest way to do that, because I can't find any tutorial about that on web.

Comment: Please explain why you want the Browser to search for that string instead of retrieving the body and using Java to search

Comment: @Marged Dude, I'm saying for the thirth time, I don't have any idea how to do that, so that's why I'm asking...
Could you write your soulution?

Comment: I am certainly not your Dude. I just asked you to clarify your question. If you don't have the time for this you better move on

Comment: @Marged calm down, I didn't wont to offent you. :D
I'm just awake for now 23 hours working on this project. :D
Deadline is midnight today, so.. you know... :D

Comment: Don't explain your situation, explain your problem. If you just want to know if the page contains a specific text then Rabia just gave the answer

Comment: @Marged I explained problem. Nope, I must search and higlight the word "test".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171510/discussion-between-neo-cortex-and-marged).

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/explanation. You should explain why and what the bigger context is because this seems to be a XY problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use the JavaScript Executor to highlight the matched element.

Sample:

```
//Partial Match of the word
WebElement matchedElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'test')]"));
         (or)
//Exact Match of the word
WebElement matchedElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='test']"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');", matchedElement);
```

Comment: Maybe we are on good way, but how to find element "test"?  :D
It's even not a element, it's string.

Comment: @NeoCortex, you can find the webelement using XPath. I have updated the WebElement finding part as well in the code. Please check

Comment: It's seems to be solution, but, when I run it, it doesn't higlight "test", but neighter I doesn't het any error. On blog there is 16 pages, but I need to search only at 1st one... Is that first check all pages so it take a while or what? :D

Comment: @Subburaj,  Your solution will highlight the element which contains text 'test',  not highlight the only word 'test' or 'testing' in a long string.  like `<p>Manual testers always try to test all possible situations</p>`, it will highlight the entire string `Manual testers always try to test all possible situations`, rather than the two words: `testers` and `'test`

Comment: @Neo,  If want to archive your goal through selenium, you have to insert plenty of HTML code and if any event triggered page whole/partial refresh during inserting, the previous inserted HTML code will disappear. So please consider it's worth to do that if you hop e the highlight effect can keep a long time.  Can you tell us your purpose of highlight.

Comment: @young 
I take screenshot of my test, where is said I have to "On the Blog page search for the word "test""
[test screenshot](http://prntscr.com/jl5hts)

Answer (score 2):

You can verify it through page source:

```
if(driver.getPageSource().contains("test")){
    System.out.println("The page contains word test");
    }
```